# Functions to manipulate (increase) probability exponentially or logaritmically?

Tags: probability, functions, special-functions, exponential-function

Very simple. I want a function to manipulate a probability in order increase it without getting out of the range of 0 to 1.

Basically a function similar to the blue lines in the following sketch:

[image]

This is to tweak a a computer simulation, so any ideas are welcome. I would be trying several of them. Right now, I can just thing of:

```
f(x)=1-(1-x)^a
```

I came up with it, but I would prefer a more standard approach for what it seems a common task, rather than a sui generis function that I am not sure it is often used.

Comment: Take into account that you need not only to keep the density probability between 1 and 0, but you need also to make the sum of all probabilities be still 1.

Comment: Seems like you are looking something like $x^{1/a}$

Comment: @AlbertMasclans, that shouldn't be a problem because it is just one, independently of other values in the simulation.

Comment: @Slungpue, I just hit my forehead so hard when I saw your answer. That totally makes sense. I guess I was thinking on rotating the exponential when I put all those minuses in my formula. Put it as an answer to accept it